# add range to Pandas describe() method

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I'm trying to do this

this original describe method for Pandas

```
       sepal_len    sepal_wid   petal_len   petal_wid
count   5.000000    5.000000    5.000000    5.0
mean    4.860000    3.280000    1.400000    0.2
std     0.207364    0.258844    0.070711    0.0
min     4.600000    3.000000    1.300000    0.2
25%     4.700000    3.100000    1.400000    0.2
50%     4.900000    3.200000    1.400000    0.2
75%     5.000000    3.500000    1.400000    0.2
max     5.100000    3.600000    1.500000    0.2
```

i need to add Range Row in describe method

```
range   0.5          0.60        0.19       0.0
```

```
       sepal_len    sepal_wid   petal_len   petal_wid
count   5.000000    5.000000    5.000000    5.0
mean    4.860000    3.280000    1.400000    0.2
std     0.207364    0.258844    0.070711    0.0
min     4.600000    3.000000    1.300000    0.2
25%     4.700000    3.100000    1.400000    0.2
50%     4.900000    3.200000    1.400000    0.2
75%     5.000000    3.500000    1.400000    0.2
max     5.100000    3.600000    1.500000    0.2
range   0.5          0.60        0.19       0.0
```

this following code I did

```
ds = data.head().describe()
rangelist = [];
for d in range(4):
    Max = ( ds.iloc[:,d].loc['max']) 
    Min = ( ds.iloc[:,d].loc['min']) 
    rangelist.append(Max-Min)

ds.append(rangelist)
```

the output give me that instead of row, columns values

```
0       petal_len   petal_wid   sepal_len   sepal_wid
count   NaN 5.000000    5.0 5.000000    5.000000
mean    NaN 1.400000    0.2 4.860000    3.280000
std     NaN 0.070711    0.0 0.207364    0.258844
min     NaN 1.300000    0.2 4.600000    3.000000
25%     NaN 1.400000    0.2 4.700000    3.100000
50%     NaN 1.400000    0.2 4.900000    3.200000
75%     NaN 1.400000    0.2 5.000000    3.500000
max     NaN 1.500000    0.2 5.100000    3.600000
0       0.5  NaN        NaN    NaN       NaN
1       0.6  NaN        NaN    NaN       NaN
2       0.2  NaN        NaN    NaN       NaN
3       0.0  NaN        NaN    NaN       NaN
```

Answer (score 5):

you can do with `loc` in one line

```
ds.loc['range'] = ds.loc['max'] - ds.loc['min']
print(ds)
       sepal_len  sepal_wid  petal_len  petal_wid
count   5.000000   5.000000   5.000000        5.0
mean    4.860000   3.280000   1.400000        0.2
std     0.207364   0.258844   0.070711        0.0
min     4.600000   3.000000   1.300000        0.2
25%     4.700000   3.100000   1.400000        0.2
50%     4.900000   3.200000   1.400000        0.2
75%     5.000000   3.500000   1.400000        0.2
max     5.100000   3.600000   1.500000        0.2
range   0.500000   0.600000   0.200000        0.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much it's worked , but i want to understand, is loc work separately for each columns

Comment: @AhmedNour Pandas does nearly all operations aligning the indexes, both the dataframe index and column headers.  So, yes, df.loc['max'] translate into df.loc['max', :] for all columns and likewise with df.loc['min'] and pandas will automatically subtract aligning column headers.